# C error: expected expression before '{' token

Tags: c

This is the code http://pastebin.com/Y7zQkVHZ

and the compiler gives me the above error. What is the mistake ?
thanks(:

Here is the code in an immediately readable form:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define round(a) {    \
    if(a < 0)    \
        ((a + 0.5) < (int)a)? (int)a: (int)a + 1;    \
    else        \
        ((a - 0.5) < (int)a)? (int)a: (int)a + 1;    \
}

#define ARRLENG 8 /* array length */

/* function prototype */
void arrRounder(double[ARRLENG]);

int main()
{
    double arr[ARRLENG] = {2.13, 6.9, 9.49999, 0.5, 8.0, 0, -2.4, -2.5};
    arrRounder(arr);
    return 0;
}

void arrRounder(double arr[ARRLENG])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < ARRLENG; i++)
        arr[i] = round(arr[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < ARRLENG; i++)
        printf("%lf\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Look closely at your round() macro and how you use it.

Comment: Multilines macro aren't evil? Isn't it better to use functions instead?

Comment: Written as a function that thing is *very* likely to inline by the optimizer from any reasonable compiler. I'm not sure what you're hoping to gain by writing it as a macro, but suspend that hope for some sanity and just write a function.

Comment: And what's wrong with using the round() function in math.h?

Answer (score 5):

Your `round()` macro is indeed a mixture of statement and expression, which is not permissible in this way.

Either you should transform the `if` into another ternary operator - which makes the whole stuff even more unreadable - or you should put it into a function.

Comment: Thanks !

and the exercise is to make a macro that rounds a double to the nearest integer, and than make a function that uses the macro to round a whole array. So the macro is must, I cant replace it with a function.

So how can I do it, so it will be readable and without errors ?

Comment: No need to transform the whole if/else into ?: since the bodies are nearly identical. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor replaces `rounder` with the macro body verbatim. So you will have a line that looks like

```
arr[i] = { ... };
```

That's not a valid C statement.

Macro invocations might look like function calls, but they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your current rounding algorithm is sound, this does the same thing in expression form:

```
#define round(a) (((a) + ((a) < 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5) < (int)(a))? (int)(a): (int)(a) + 1)
```

Note all the extra parentheses around `a`, in case it's an unparenthesized expression. This is best (necessary) practice in macros.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*macro*/
#define round(a) (((a - (int)a) < 0.5) ? (int)a : (int)(a + 1))
/*const*/
#define ARRLENG 8 /* array length */

/* function prototype */
void arrRounder(double[ARRLENG]);

/*main*/
int main()
{
    double arr[ARRLENG] = {2.13, 6.9, 9.49999, 0.5, 8.0, 0, -2.4, -2.5};
    arrRounder(arr);
    return 0;
}

/*function declaration*/
void arrRounder(double arr[ARRLENG])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < ARRLENG; i++)
        arr[i] = round(arr[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < ARRLENG; i++)
        printf("%lf\n", arr[i]);
}
```

I have not tried this code with other numbers but should work fine. Try to find a way to avoid the cast operator `(int)` because may have impredictable outcomes.

Comment: My bad, the solution doesn't account for negative numbers and I've seen now the Jim Balter answer.

Answer (score -1):

as per me you should use simple braces instead of curley. check out for the Syntax of defining a macro.

Comment: Won't help here, if no other things are changed as well.

Comment: What is "as per me"? What is "simple braces"? Do you mean parentheses? If so, you haven't given enough detail.

Comment: ok,sorry for that.simple brackets means" () ".We can have macro using parenthesis instead of curley.                                        ex:                                                                 " #define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b)) "